# UIScrollview error when call UIViewcontroller in landscape mode

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, storyboard

I have a `UIScrollview` that is loaded with other two `UIViewControllers`. The main `UIViewcontroller` has the orientation locked to portrait mode and the last view has a button that call another `uiviewcontroller` with a `UIImageview` that needs to rotate depending of the mobile orientation.

Everything works fine except that if I rotate the mobile in landscape mode and then press the button to call the `UIViewcontroller` with the image in it, the `UIScrollview` is showed halfway or from page1 when I return back from the image to the main scrollview.

The main `UIViewcontroller` is locked using:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
```

here the project file: https://github.com/salvonos/OrientationScrollView

[image]

[image]

Comment: unable to download the project file.

Comment: sorry changed the link

Comment: the project is empty

Comment: It should be fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using:

```
    var autoRotate: Bool?
    var orientationMode: UIInterfaceOrientationMask?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            autoRotate = false
            orientationMode = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.autoRotate = true
        self.orientationMode = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }


     override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
            return autoRotate!
        }


        override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            return orientationMode!
        }
```